# Configuration for AD-Groups and special Users /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Tags: linux, authentication, security, ssh, sshd

The Configuration of the **/etc/ssh/sshd_config** looks like this, the members in **ad-group1** and **ad-group2** do have access to the system with **SSH**, the members of **ad-group1** who are not in **ad-group2** don't have access to the system.

Status Quo

```
Match Group ad-group1,ad-group2
    AllowUsers *

Match Group ad-group1,!ad-group2
    DenyUsers *
```

The Problem is there are two Users, which should have access via **SSH** too, but there aren't members of ad-group2,how do I have to edit the **sshd_config**, that User **ad-user1** and **ad-user2** have acess even if there aren't in **ad-group2**

I thought of something like this:

```
Match Group ad-group1,ad-group2
    AllowUsers ad-user1 ad-user2

Match Group ad-group1,!ad-group2
    DenyUsers *
```

but this shows not the right effect

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please re-read the guidance for the tags you've used.  This is clearly a question about system configuration, not about __programming__, so is off-topic for Stack Overflow.  It _might_ be suitable for [sf]: consult the Help Centre for the site before you post.